# lebesgue continuos and norm, functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded function, measurable in $[0,1]$ ,for $g\in { L }^{ 2 }[0,1]$ we define ${ T }_{ f }g=fg $. Show that $T_{f}$ is continuous and calculate its norm

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f \neq 0$. I will assume that $f$ is real valued. $|T_f(g)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \|g\|_2$ so $\|T\| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$. To show that $\|T\| = \|f\|_{\infty}$ let $E=\{x: |f(x)| >\|f\|_{\infty} -\epsilon \}$ and  take $g=c sgn (f) I_E$ where $c=(\mu (E))^{-1/2}$. I will let you complete the proof of the equation $\|T\| = \|f\|_{\infty}$ using this function .